# after nodejs update i get this error: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "600204c674086624b9de76e2" at path "classId" for model "Message"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

this is my code:

```
async function allMessage(roomId){
     await Message.find({ classId: roomId }).sort({ date: -1 }).limit(4)
    .populate('userId', 'name')// just select name
    .exec(function(allMessage){

        console.log(allMessage);
    })
}
```

and this is my model structure:

```
userId:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},

classId:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Classroom'
},

message:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},

date:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
```

but i get this error: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "600204c674086624b9de76e2" at path "classId" for model "Message"

I try to change roomId to ObjectId with this code:

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId(roomId)
```

but i get this error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

befor updating the nodejs it works fine. I confused now. what should I do?

Comment: Try this syntax new ObjectID (id) to find the record in mongo like Message.find({ classId: new ObjectID(roomId) }).

Comment: try using trim() on the string id you are getting and then pass.

Comment: well done @NamitPiriya  roomId.trim() works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using trim() on the string id you are getting and then pass it in the query